# site path not working properly

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nginx

My site is hosted in Ubuntu , apache . 
when entering the path as **sample.com/reports/** its working properly .. 
but when entering **sample.com/reports** its not working .. i want both to result in loading **sample.com/reports/index.php** ..

sites-enabled entry in nginx is

```
location /reports {
   proxy_pass host:port;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_read_timeout 600s;
}
```

How to configure this to load both to same index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `location /reports/`.

http://nginx.org/r/location

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, scgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, or memcached_pass, then in response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended.

Comment: thanks @alexeyten .. 

i changed the file as you said .   still when i goto sample.com/reports/ its working 
but when i enter sample.com/reports its showing the path as sample.com:8000/reports/ and a message **" could not connect to sample:8000 "** ...